# Existence of the integral 1/x: x [1,2].

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm working on a Real Analysis problem that has had me stumped for quite a while now. I would really value any kinds of hints anyone can give me.

**Problem:**

Show that $\int^2_1 1/x$ exists by considering the partitions of $[1,2]$ into $n$ equal subintervals and showing that the difference between the upper sums and lower sums goes to zero.

**Attempt:**

Let $\mathcal{P} = \left \{ t_0, t_1 , ...,t_n \right \}$ be the partition over the interval $[1,2]$. Note that $t_0 = 1$ and $t_n = 2$. The lower and upper sums are defined as $$L(1/x,\mathcal{P}_n) = \sum^n_{i=1}m_i(t_i-t_{i-1})$$ and $$U(1/x,,\mathcal{P}_n)= \sum^n_{t=1}M_i(t_i-t_{i-1}),$$ respectively. Also, $m_i = \inf \{f(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i $} and $M_i = \sup\{ f(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i \}$. On some ith interval it follows that $$M_i = f(t_{i-1}) = 1/t_{i-1} \hspace{2mm}  \text{and}\hspace{2mm} m_i = f(t_i) = 1/t_i.$$ Since we are making $n$ equal intervals we can also see that $t_i - t_{i-1} = \frac{(2-1)}{n} = 1/n,$ and that the $t_i = i/n.$ This implies that we can write the lower and upper sums as, $$ L = \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{t_i} \frac{1}{n} = \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{n}{i} \frac{1}{n} = \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{i}$$ and $$U =  \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{t_{i-1}} \frac{1}{n} = \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{n}{i-1} \frac{1}{n} = \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{i-1}$$ which are both harmonic series that diverge (or have nasty partial sums, anyway).

**Comments**

So this is where I am stuck. I can't get around these nasty harmonic sums. Intuitively, there has got to be a solution... surely.. I mean I can integrate it naively, and it seems to work. Thanks very much for any assistance.

Comment: Your index is off $i=2$ otherwise you come to the issue of $\frac {1}{0}$ in the upper bound. With that said it looks good so far, and you're correct that each is harmonic. However what about |L-U|? Is that still harmonic?

Comment: $t_i$ should not be equal to $i/n$ (that wouldn't even be in the domain for large $n$). That's the problem. Otherwise, your procedure is right.

Comment: $t_i=1+i/n$ instead, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Federico yes! Oh that's excellent. Thanks very much for picking up on that. If I go ahead and take the $| L-U|$, as Sentinel135 said (thanks for your comment as well!!) then I get something like $$ \left| \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{-1}{(n+i)^2 - (n+i)} \right|.$$ I just went ahead and calculated a few terms to see that the series sums to $\frac{1}{2n}$. Since the absolute difference between the lower and upper sum is equal to $1/2n$, $n$ can become arbitrarily large to make the difference arbitrarily small! That's it! Thanks so much for helping me!